# Why Apple watch Nike+ is in same price as normal watch?

Tags: watchos, apple-watch, health.app

I am planning to buy an Apple Watch series 3 (GPS only) but confused between normal and Nike+ edition. If I purchase Nike+ edition, am I losing anything that is in Normal watch? If Nike+ edition is (Normal + Nike) then why Apple has kept price of both same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apple Watch Series 3 and Nike+ Edition are exactly the same hardware, just different bands and some preloaded software (which you can manually install on a plain Apple Watch).  It's the same price because it's essentially the same hardware in the box

From [Apple Insider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/10/10/should-you-buy-the-apple-watch-nike-series-4-instead-of-the-standard-model):

> Last year's Nike+ Apple Watch Series 3 wasn't much different from the
>   standard version making it a bit tough to choose between the two
>   models.

What's different with Series 4....

- Not available in Gold or Stainless Steel
- Nike exclusive faces that immediately take you to "complications" in the Nike Training App
- Nike specific bands (reflective) geared toward training (can't buy separately from Apple's website; off of eBay, well that a different story)